# Installing an SSL certificate and running nitrogen webframe work over cowboy server over https

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, cowboy, nitrogen

I am developing an application using nitrogen web framework over cowboy web server. When i run the server over http is works perfectly well. Now in production the application must run on https.

I have modified the **cowboy.config** file in the etc directory of nitrogen from default

```
% vim: ts=4 sw=4 et ft=erlang
[
{cowboy,[
    {bind_address,"127.0.0.1"},
    {port,80},
    {server_name,nitrogen},       
    {document_root,"./site/static"},
    %% some comments.........
    {static_paths, ["/js/","/images/","/css/","/nitrogen/","/favicon.ico"]}
]}
].
```

to this one

```
% vim: ts=4 sw=4 et ft=erlang
[
{cowboy,[
    {bind_address,"127.0.0.1"},
    {port,443},
    {server_name,nitrogen},
    {cacertfile, "Path/cacert.pem"},
    {certfile, "Path/webservercert.pem"},
    {keyfile, "Path/webserverkey.pem"},
    {password, "webserverkeypassphrase"}
    {document_root,"./site/static"},
    %% some comments.........
    {static_paths, ["/js/","/images/","/css/","/nitrogen/","/favicon.ico"]}
]}
].
```

Where **Path** is the absolute path to the SSL certificate that I generated and signed it by myself using **openSSL**. I take my site name as domainname.com but i first create a CA following openSSl documentation

I also modified the **Supervisor callbacks** in the **nitrogen_sup.erl** file found in **nitrogen/site/scr** from the default

```
%% ===================================================================
%% Supervisor callbacks
%% ===================================================================

init([]) ->
%% Start the Process Registry...
application:start(crypto),
application:start(nprocreg),
application:start(ranch),

%% Start Cowboy...
application:start(cowboy),
{ok, BindAddress} = application:get_env(cowboy, bind_address),
{ok, Port} = application:get_env(cowboy, port),
{ok, ServerName} = application:get_env(cowboy, server_name),
{ok, DocRoot} = application:get_env(cowboy, document_root),
{ok, StaticPaths} = application:get_env(cowboy, static_paths),  

io:format("Starting Cowboy Server (~s) on ~s:~p, root: '~s'~n",
          [ServerName, BindAddress, Port, DocRoot]),

Dispatch = init_dispatch(DocRoot, StaticPaths),

{ok, _} = cowboy:start_http(http, 100,     
        [
            {port, Port}               
        ], [
    {env, [{dispatch, Dispatch}]},
    {max_keepalive, 50}
]),

{ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10}, []} }.
```

to this one below

```
%% ===================================================================
%% Supervisor callbacks
%% ===================================================================

init([]) ->
   %% Start the Process Registry...

   application:start(crypto),    
   application:start(nprocreg),
   application:start(ranch),   

   %% Start Cowboy...
   application:start(cowboy),
   {ok, BindAddress} = application:get_env(cowboy, bind_address),
   {ok, Port} = application:get_env(cowboy, port),
   {ok, ServerName} = application:get_env(cowboy, server_name),
   {ok, DocRoot} = application:get_env(cowboy, document_root),
   {ok, StaticPaths} = application:get_env(cowboy, static_paths),
   {ok, CAcertfile} = application:get_env(cowboy, cacertfile),
   {ok, Certfile} = application:get_env(cowboy, certfile),
   {ok, Keyfile} = application:get_env(cowboy, keyfile),
   {ok, Password} = application:get_env(cowboy, password),

   io:format("Starting Cowboy Server (~s) on ~s:~p, root: '~s'~n",
          [ServerName, BindAddress, Port, DocRoot]),

   Dispatch = init_dispatch(DocRoot, StaticPaths),
   {ok, _} = cowboy:start_https(https, 100,
     [
        {port, Port},
        {cacertfile, CAcertfile}, 
        {certfile, Certfile},
        {keyfile,  Keyfile},
        {password, Password}            
    ], [         
    {env, [{dispatch, Dispatch}]},
    {max_keepalive, 50}
]),

{ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10}, []} }.
```

Using sync:go() the file compiles and reloads. However i closed nitrogen and started it again.

in the shell I use the curl utility to test if the server is listening

```
$ curl --cacert Absolute_path/cacert.pem -i https://domainname.com
```

the response is posite as the contents on the index page are displayed in the shell

However, when i go to Firefox browser it throws a security warning which i admitted an except that i known its cause i permanently add to the exceptions. When I try getting the page again the browser throws this error.

```
Secure Connection Failed

The key does not support the requested operation.

(Error code: sec_error_invalid_key)

.The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
.Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem. Alternatively, use the command found in the help menu to report this broken site.
```

When i checked in the nitrogen console if found this error report

```
(nitrogen@127.0.0.1)4> user@user:~/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen$ 
user@user:~/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen$ sudo ./bin/nitrogen console
Exec: /home/user/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/erts-5.10.4/bin/erlexec  -boot       /home/user/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/releases/2.2.2/nitrogen -mode interactive  -config /home/user/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/etc/app.config -config /home/user/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/etc/cowboy.config -config /home/user/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/etc/sync.config -args_file /home/dotshule/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/etc/vm.args -- console
Root: /home/dotshule/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:5] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
(nitrogen@127.0.0.1)1> Starting Cowboy Server (nitrogen) on 127.0.0.1:443, root: './site/static'

=ERROR REPORT==== 20-Feb-2014::14:51:12 ===
SSL: certify: tls_connection.erl:375:Fatal error: unknown ca
```

Now what i do not understand is whether the server is the one refusing my certificate or i have skipped a step, or one or two steps have gone wrong or the problem is on my self created CA (root certificate **cacert.pem**) or the problem is on openSSL!

I have now become suspicious that may be if i generate my **CSR** and send it to the **trusted CA** such as symantec, digcert, thawte, geotrust, ..etc. the resulting certificate may also fail to work.

I need your help please on this https of nitrogen over cowboy webserver issue. Thaks for all your help so far....

Comment: Does it generate the same error on all browsers?

Comment: Yes i have tried, IE8, Safari, Chrome, Opera as wells as Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why cowboy would be throwing that particular error ([tls_connection.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/23790daf1a2d384b0fc11c655fa825151d9fa420/lib/ssl/src/tls_connection.erl) is actually a part of Erlang, rather than Cowboy or Nitrogen).

That said, when it comes to running SSL with Nitrogen, I usually just recommend to users to use nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Nitrogen, and there are nginx configuration examples on the Nitrogen site at http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/config.html (scroll down to SSL-only example).

I realize that's not exactly ideal, so alternatively, I'd see if nginx or apache are able to successfully serve sample pages with the same key/cert combos.  Obviously, the "unknown ca" error is saying that Erlang doesn't like the fact that it's a self-signed certificate. So you could experiment with using other signed certs/keys you may have lying around, or generate a real one for free at StartSSL.com and see if the error continues presenting itself.

Again, none of these are *solid* answers, but they should help point you in a number of directions to help solving your problems.

Personally, I run all my Nitrogen instances behind nginx and let nginx deal with the SSL and load-balancing.

Comment: There is a feature in cowboy which is forcing me to try up to success this option. However Chops, this is what i have got from your help - if the certificate is from a **known ca**, definitely it will work. I am convinced the it will work because `"curl --cacert /../.../cacert.pem https://domainname.com"` works! **-- cacert** option is to solve the **'unknown ca'** issue when using **curl** utility.

Answer (score 0):

My methodology actually works, I have successfully tested it using SYMANTEC and VERISIGN SSL certificates and it could be a formal way of installing SSL certificates on Cowboy web server.